Решение задачи методом рекурсии вместо цикла
Пытаюсь решить задачку, через цикл, множество и map проще простого, но в условии написано без циклов, только рекурсией.
Код:
def summa(n):

    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n + summa(n - 1)

    def main():
        if not (num := input("введите число: ")):
            return
        summa(num)
        main()

Условие:

Напишите программу, которая будет складывать числа, введенные пользователем. Сигналом к окончанию ввода должна служить пустая строка. Отобразите на экране сумму значений (или 0.0, если пользователь сразу же пропустил ввод). Решите эту задачу с использованием рекурсии. В вашей программе не должны присутствовать циклы.

Подсказка:

В теле вашей рекурсивной функции должен производиться запрос одного числа у пользователя, после чего должно быть принято решение о том, производить ли еще один рекурсивный вызов. Ваша функция не должна принимать аргументов, а возвращать будет числовое значение.


Ну вы же делаете совсем не то. Условие остановки рекурсии - пустая строка, а не какое-то там число n. И почему не прислушались к Подсказка. В теле вашей рекурсивной функции должен производиться запрос одного числа?

@MBo Суммировать насколько я понял нужно список, а как без цикла рекурсией записать числа в список и еще и прервать нулем?

Нет, никакие списки не нужны.
По подсказке: вводим строку.
Если она пустая, возвращаем ноль.
Если непустая, то преобразуем в число (здесь я не учитываю возможность ошибок, ввода произвольного текста), вызываем функцию дальше, и результат складываем с числом, полученным на этом уровне рекурсии
def mysum():
    s = input()
    if s:
        return  int(s) + mysum()
    else:
        return 0

print(mysum())


2
4

6


"if s:" я не знал что так можно

Ну каким-то способом же нужно проверить, что строка не пустая, так проще всего. Можно и len(s)>0

а так if s != "" ?

Тоже вариант. Но обратите внимание: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing , так что пустая строка, список, 0 и т.д. оцениваются  в условных операторах как False

if s: - рекомендуется сообществом Питона для проверки на непустоту для строк и коллекций. Я не очень люблю такие финты, но следую правилам.
